# Best approach for rearranging DOM according to screen size

Tags: jquery, dom, responsive-design, dom-manipulation

I have a standard website which contains its navigation part way down the page.  When resized down to 980px a media query kicks in and the navigation needs to change appearance (easy) but also change position within the DOM so that it's at the top of the page.  I can't use CSS positioning for this as it just wouldn't work.

At the moment I'm toying with binding some jQuery logic to the page load/resize/change orientation events like this:

```
var mobileBreakPoint = 980;
$(window).bind('load resize orientationchange', function () {
    if ($(window).width() <= mobileBreakPoint) {
        $('.primary').insertAfter('.new-placeholder');
    } else {
        $('.primary').insertAfter('.original-placeholder');
    }
});
```

However, firstly I'm not sure whether using javascript to move quite large chunks of HTML around the page is a good idea performance-wise (bearing in mind this site is expected to work well on a mobile, hence the media queries!); and secondly, my code above would need to use something like jQuery '.on()' to move the DOM structure back to its original position, else it doesn't recognise the selector anymore once it has been moved, which again would seem to add quite a significant processing burden.

I wondered if anyone had any good ideas on this?  Is this the best way forward?  Should I stop worrying about performance or should I just render the navigation twice and use CSS to show/hide the different versions?

I gather there may be some very cutting edge CSS3 stuff to do this kind of thing but I need to support back to IE7 so that's probably not an option.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you give it `position:fixed`, and according top offset, it should work.

Considerable layout rearrangements in responsive designs are an open topic, and there is no common solution I guess: either you hide unneeded stuff [e.g. the `hidden-*` Bootstrap classes], either you duplicate some stuff [avoidable imo].

Nevertheless, have a look at [enquire.js](http://wicky.nillia.ms/enquire.js/), it may help you for sure.